Risk assessment on handling sodium, lithium, magnesium, mercury and noble gases
I want to do an activity with my students where we study some basic properties of some elements of different groups. I'm concerned about some hazards with some of these elements. I work under a simple fume hood.
My concerns are:

Pure sodium/lithium/magnesium: Is it safe to handle at room temperature and standard humidity conditions? Once in stored in mineral oil, how safe is it to keep it in chemical storage? Given that all the groups together might use 0.2 g of Na, would the H2 produced be an hazard?
mercury: is it safe to put a couple of drops of mercury in the watch glass at room temperature? I'm mostly concerned about the fumes and the inhalation hazards.
noble gases: I saw some small Tesla coil to excite the noble gases (eg. powered by a 9V battery); how safe are these tesla coil? Are there some hazards?

I would appreciate any information that you have about it.

I would steer clear of sodium and mercury. Especially if you need to ask like this.

Try a gram or so of gallium: it is liquid at body temperature. Those little Tesla coils are relatively safe, though you won’t soon forget it if you inadvertently touch the business end.

You could demonstrate using all these for your students. I you cannot do this safely yourself then you definitely should not let your students anywhere near any of them.

Thank you all for the replies. I never worked with these elements myself so I don't have direct experience. I'm collecting information from different sources (including a university professor) before I give it a try myself. Than I'll eventually do it with the class. I'm planning simple experiments like showing the reactivity of alkali (eg. by throwing Na in water). Having seen some videos on YT it seems doable since I would work with a couple of students at each time under a fume hood.
Gallium is a nice idea! Thx

Sodium, like all alkaline metals, is dangerous to use. If you throw a small amount (less than one gram) of such a metal in one or two liters water, a violent exothermic reaction happens projecting hot hydrogen, light and some caustic hydroxide in the vicinity. It is dangerous and should be done with care in a hood.
Mercury is the contrary. It does not react with water or air. It was used for years by all dentists in the world up to the middle of the 20th century, when the toxicity of mercury compounds was proven. Mercury vapors and mercury compounds are toxic. But liquid mercury (or mercury-silver alloys) was used for blocking dental caries in all countries around the world without any problems up to the middle of the 20th century. It was then replaced by ceramics.
Mercury vapors should not be inhaled because it is toxic at high doses. It is not easy to inhale a lot of mercury vapors. But putting a couple of drops of mercury in the watch glass at room temperature for an hour or two is not dangerous. I have done it in all my classes in the years 1970 - 1980, without any problems. Of course I know that, now, it is not allowed anymore to use mercury in chemistry courses.
I know a lot of present teachers will protest against my present opinion. Law is law. Law must be respected. Nobody can act illegally. So I will not recommend using mercury as it was in the 20th century. But I think I must mention what I know about its former use.

Thank you for your insight! Very helpful! What do you think about 0.025 g of Na in water? I believe it should be fairly safe and wouldn't even ignite.

@ Pierpaolo. Using a couple of milligrams sodium will not ignite. It is too little. The reaction will be finished after a couple of seconds.
